# C# UWP using not referencing functions correctly?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm no expert at this stuff so apologies for anything being named incorrectly or missing information.

I have a lot of functions that are referenced in a lot of different views and their rescpective .cs files so I've put them all in a seperate class file in the project (Functions.cs) and am referencing them. They're separated into groups in public static classes in this file as below.

```
namespace Opticos
{
    public static class OpticsMaths //A bunch of functions regarding maths of optics
    {
        public static double ReflectionCalculator(string material, double WL) ...
        various other functions
    }
    public static class DataAccess//A bunch of functions for querying a database
    {
        public static List<string> GetDataColumn(string table, string column)...
        various other functions
    }
}
```

I then put this at the top of my cs files in my views.

```
using static Opticos.OpticsMaths;
using static Opticos.DataAccess;
```

In any case where I want to call a function (e.g. GetDataColumn) from DataAccess, I just type this and it works fine.

```
List<string> materials = GetDataColumn("Materials", "Material");
```

But the OpticsMaths don't work like this. I need to type OpticsMaths.ReflectionCalculator, rather than ReflectionCalculator to call it. Is there anything obvious I should check (or any proper way to do this. It only does it for the OpticsMaths class. There are 8 seperate classes and the rest work as expected.

//-----Edit-----//

I've deleted nearly everything from my project to try and see what is going on. I only have the Functions.cs file and one view page and its .cs file (CalculatorsPage.xaml & CalculatorsPage.xaml.cs)

I've reduced my Functions.cs file to the following.

```
using System;

namespace Opticos
{
    public static class OpticsMaths
    {
        public static double ETCalc(this double d, double t, double r1, double r2)
        {
            double h1 = r1 != 0 ? Math.Sign(r1) * (Math.Abs(r1) - Math.Sqrt(4 * Math.Pow(r1, 2) - Math.Pow(d, 2)) / 2) : 0;
            double h2 = r2 != 0 ? -Math.Sign(r2) * (Math.Abs(r2) - Math.Sqrt(4 * Math.Pow(r2, 2) - Math.Pow(d, 2)) / 2) : 0;
            return t - h1 - h2;
        }
    }
}
```

The CalculatorsPage.xaml.cs is as follows.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using static Opticos.OpticsMaths;

namespace Opticos.Views
{
    public sealed partial class CalculatorsPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CalculatorsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value)) { return; }
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
        StorageFile CWLfile; int SelectedChartFilter = 1;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e); double test = ETCalc(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The ETCalc function still says it does not exist in the context but if I call it as OpticsMaths.ETCalc it works.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - and check that the problem *really* only occurs in a UWP app. (If you can reproduce it in a simple console app, that will make it much easier to reproduce.) You should also provide an example of trying to call `ReflectionCalculator` and the precise error message you receive. (I would say that `ReflectionCalculator` is an odd name for a method - I'd expect it to be `CalculateReflection`... usually *classes* are nouns, but *methods* are verbs.)

Comment: That identifier `ReflectionCalculator`, are you declaring that in multiple places (other static classes)? What error did you get when you used it without class name?

Comment: I'm not using the identifier elsewhere. It isn't unique to the identifier, it is unique to the class OpticsMaths and happens everywhere, with every function within that class. I get CS0103 ("The name 'ReflectionCalculator' does not exist in the current context") when I try and call the function without the OpticsMaths prefix.

Comment: That static use is part of your issue... properly create the classes and you shouldn't need  static unless you are really needing their contents to remain post execution of their respective methods. You will find that there going to be issues from the static usage.  Some cases of static usage are fine, i don't believe from what you have posted its necessary.